# Emacs eval-print-last-sexp verbosity level

Tags: emacs, elisp

When in `*scratch*`, <kbd>C-j</kbd> calls `eval-print-last-sexp`.
However, I can't get the default behavior when I do this:

```
(local-set-key
 (kbd "C-j") 
 (lambda()(interactive) (eval-print-last-sexp)))
```

Now when evaluation result is integer, its octal and hex
representations are printed as well:

```
(+ 2 2)
4 (#o4, #x4)
```

What is the cause of this behavior and how can I turn it off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional output comes from the function `eval-expression-print-format` (which see).
In `lisp-interaction-mode` the variable `this-command` is set to `eval-expression-print-format`. You just need to set it similarly:

```
(local-set-key
 (kbd "C-j") 
 (lambda()(interactive)
 (setq this-command 'eval-last-sexp)
 (eval-print-last-sexp)))
```